# Add label to checkbox when content type is created

Tags: drupal-7

How can i set this option in "true" programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$field_instance = field_info_instance('entity_type', 'field_name', 'bundle_name');`

`$field_instance['widget']['settings']['display_label'] = '1';
 $field_instance['widget']['active'] = 1;`

`field_update_instance($field_instance);`